# Sub-space topoplogy and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau_X)$ be a topological space. $Y\subseteq X$ gives a subspace topology defined by $\tau_Y=\{Y\cap U: U\in\tau_X\}$. Now consider $A\subseteq Y$. My question is does $X\backslash A \in \tau_X \implies Y\backslash A \in \tau_Y$. Basically if $A$ closed in $X$ implies that $A$ is closed in $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is closed because $A=Y \cap A$ where $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Sweet...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes** because $X\setminus A = \complement_X (A)$ and $Y\setminus A = Y \cap \complement_X (A)$.